# Date value saving as 0000-00-00 00:00:00 into a TIMESTAMP field when the query seems to be in ok format

Tags: php, mysql, sql, date, datetime

I have a `event` table where the fields are like:

```
id  int(11)
event_id    int(11)
title   varchar(300)
url varchar(30)
tags    varchar(300)
end_date    timestamp
created_at  timestamp
```

Now I am executing a query like:

```
INSERT INTO `events` 
(`event_id`, `title`, `url`, `tags`, `end_date`) 
VALUES 
('448761', 'event title', 'http://calendar.google.com/', 'reserve|call|urgent','2014-07-25 08:00:00')
```

I am generating the value of the `end_date` via the following code:

```
...
$end_date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($_POST['end_date']));
...
```

But after running the query the value stored at the DB is `0000-00-00 00:00:00`!!!! The query doesn't even give an error.

What I might be missing? How can I get rid of this?

Thanks in advance for the answer.

Comment: Just use `strototime` for timestamp `$end_date = strototime($_POST['end_date']);` no need `date` function

Comment: is `$_POST['end_date']` has a value and is like `1307595105`?

Comment: Is `strototime` a typo in your question? Perhaps you mean `strtotime`?

Comment: A Mysql timestamp is NOT a unix timestamp! It does NOT support the usual "number of seconds since epoch". So a strtotime alone will not work here.

Comment: Allways check PHP error logs and mysqli_error messages first. You will very likely see your errors there. (Especially if it really was that typo above.)

Comment: @Jim, it's a typo when I typed here. Thanks for pointing.

Comment: @ToBe, That was the first thing I have checked - and since there was no sign of error there - I posted here. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Are you absolutly sure that the query posted above is actually the sql that was executed? Im sure it is not. Better echo/dump all queries before execution to debug this.

Comment: I support ToBe's statement. There is nothing wrong with your insertion value illustration. Try to dump the queries that are finally sent to the database.

Comment: @ToBe, I am absolutely sure that I have copied and pasted the query straight from debugger and log file.  :-)

Comment: The query you posted should work fine. There is something else going on.